# Stackedcolumn chart has gaps and y value is not starting at 0

Tags: c#, asp.net

[I have a data like this in my database:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDjpH.png)

[But when I output this on a stackedcolumn, I get this result and it has gap and it didnt start at 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td6l8.png)

Here's my code:

```
   string query = "SELECT * FROM TBL_SAMPLE INNER JOIN TBL_AREA ON TBL_SAMPLE.AREA = TBL_AREA.AREA";
            DataTable dt = GetData(query);

            //Get the DISTINCT Foods.
            List<string> countries = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                      select p.Field<string>("FOOD")).Distinct().ToList();

            //Loop through the Foods.
            foreach (string food in countries)
            {




                //Add Series to the Chart.
                Chart1.Series.Add(new Series(food));
                Chart1.Series[food].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;


                //Get the Area for each Food.
                int[] x = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                           where p.Field<string>("FOOD") == food
                           select p.Field<int>("AREA_ID")).ToArray();

                //Get the Total each food.
                int[] y = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                           where p.Field<string>("FOOD") == food
                           select p.Field<int>("TOTAL")).ToArray();


                Chart1.Series[food].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
                Chart1.Series[food].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);


            }

            Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Your AREA_ID is 1, 2 and 3. Do you want AREA_ID - 1 (`SELECT *, AREA_ID - 1 AS X FROM ...`) for your x axis?

Comment: My problem is the 3rd series has a gap, it didn't start at 0. Look at the 2nd image

Comment: Okay, now I understand. Area 3 does not have fries and burgers. I would try to supply 0 values for TOTAL so that each AREA_ID has all types of food. Like this: `SELECT foods.FOOD, areas.AREA, COALESCE(ts.TOTAL, 0), areas.AREA_ID 
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT FOOD FROM ts1.TBL_SAMPLE ts1) foods
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ta1.AREA, ta1.AREA_ID FROM TBL_AREA ta1) areas
   LEFT JOIN TBL_SAMPLE ts ON (ts.FOOD = foods.FOOD AND ts.AREA = areas.AREA);`